# Configure Ninject for WF services to be hosted in IIS

Tags: workflow-foundation, ninject-extensions

I have a asp.net application. I am using Ninject to resolve dependencies. 
I am using WF Services which will be hosted on IIS.  These services will be consumed by my asp.net application.

For WF I have a class library for custom activities, which is referenced in the WF Services library. I want to use Ninject for any dependencies in both the WF projects.
I am using [Inject] attribute.

I have tried a lot but no success.

Please can any help me configure Ninject in WF Services library. I am using WF extension of Ninject.